# Lua 5.2 adding luasocket (unstable)

Tags: lua, luasocket

Im trying to use luasocket with lua 5.2. i downloaded the code form the git repository and built it. then made a make install so that it generated core.dll and mime.dll. put those into the custom lua program directory [CPATH] im developing and tried loading it. But i get following error message:

```
Failed at error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'D:\[..myprogram..]\socket\core.dll':
Module was not found.
```

how can i check if the dll is correct. or did i do anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the exact error you are getting? I get a different message: "error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'D:\....\socket\core.dll': The specified module could not be found." Are you setting "package.path" and "package.cpath" values in the script?

Comment: Yes that is the error message is the same as yours. I translated the last sentence from german. I think the paths are ok as it finds the file and says cannot load the module from it. Hmmm... Im happy its not only me. But how do we fix this?

Comment: UPDATE: I also tried referencing socket.core to socket as i found in a forum... without success 
package.loaded["socket.core"] = package.loaded["socket"]

Answer (score 1):

Is your executable residing in the same directory as your lua files?
Try putting the dll in the directory of your executable.

Comment: yes it is! it can find the dll. the proglem is it cannot load the module form the dll.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are loading socket modules that are compiled for Lua 5.1, not Lua 5.2 (or at least it's the same error I get in a case like that). Is it possible that you have socket module for Lua 5.1 somewhere in your path? It may come with LuaForWindows or another package. You can try to remove/move the socket DLLs you compiled (for Lua 5.2) and see if you get the same error.

Comment: i tried that already. if i remove the dll, the error is that it cannot locate the file. if i put i there then it says it cannot load the module from the file. i checked the version again and it is #define LUASOCKET_VERSION    "LuaSocket 2.1-rc1"